# JavaScript function call not triggering

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Can anyone help in this one?

I have a simple link:

```
<a href="javascript:ShareOnFacebook()" title="Share on Facebook"
   class="btn btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

and a simple function call:

```
function ShareOnFacebook() {
    alert("shared");
}
```

And the function is just not called. I really don't know what is going on. There must be a solution but I'm not seeing it.

The debugger says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ShareOnFacebook is not defined

UPDATE

The method is called correctly when the page is loaded for the first time. Every time I reload the page the method is not being called.

Comment: Is the function on the page itself or defined in an external file?

Comment: It is working on fiddle. see http://jsfiddle.net/r7e9r861/

Comment: Have you clicked the link?

Comment: Have you defined the function before its used ?

Comment: @IswantoSan you're kidding me.

Comment: @PamioSolanky Thanks, you gave me a hint. I put the method before the link and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work fine. Just make sure you define the function in a way that your HTML can see it. For example, before you use it in the HTML.

```js
function ShareOnFacebook() {
  alert('hello')
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:ShareOnFacebook()" title="Share on Facebook"
   class="btn btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You use the following script instead of your html.

```
<a onclick="ShareOnFacebook()" title="Share on Facebook" class="btn btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a>
```